Instead of shutting down, the laptop goes into sleep mode
I have a fedora distribution, every time I click on the "shutdown" menu, the laptop goes into sleep mode. If you wake up from sleep mode, it will just be a black screen with a blinking cursor. But if you exit through the "systemctl poweroff", then there is no such problem. (I also want to say that my laptop is so unknown that I can't even find out the model of the motherboard)

Are you using Fedora's default Gnome environment? I think you can configure what that menu point does in Gnome, but I'm not sure.
